# ParserError("String does not contain a date: %s", timestr) error

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, parsing

I am trying to parse an array of dates, from a large dataset, in my pandas dataframe.

to be clearer each row in my dataframe has an array of dates. most of them are nones or dates. e.g.

```
0         [None, None, None]
1         [None, None, None]
2         [None, None, None]
3               [None, None]
4         [None, None, None]
```

the column above is my date column. And in the below i am iterating through it.

```
for date in date_list:
    if date is not None and date != "None":
        date = parser.parse(date)
        year = date.year
        month = date.month
```

But unfortunately I'm getting this error:

```
raise ParserError("String does not contain a date: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: String does not contain a date:
```

i try and break this own further to see what issue is and try another way:

```
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].apply(str)

for row in df['DATE']:
    for element in row.split(','):
        if element is not None and element != "None" and element is not True:
            print(element)
```

but nothing prints when there are many nones as you can see above, so not sure why this is. can somebody assist?

Comment: i think its a blank value. you should add a check for ```""```

Comment: i've tried adding and date != "" but it still does not work

Comment: You could do a `try-except`, but without knowing the source of the error it is impossible to say how the error should be handled.

Comment: You could also check the `len` of the (stripped) string

Comment: tried len and still the error

Answer (score -3):

In line one of the error you can see the code that generates the seconds line: It parses the timestring into the %s. As the second line has nothing after the colon, I guess the timestring is empty.
But that does not necessary mean that your `date` is an empty string! The conversion from your date to the timestring just returns an empty string so I guess your date is None, although you checked that... idk